# Copy to clipboard without appending textarea

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have the following code for chrome addon's js to copy some certain data to clipboard from a certain webpage(I will write code to get data from the webpage later).

```js
// 1. Create the button
var testButton = document.createElement("button");
testButton.innerHTML = "Copy";

// 2. Append somewhere
var btnPos = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-userdetails")[0];
btnPos.appendChild(testButton);

// 3. Add event handler
testButton.addEventListener ("click", copyToClipboard);

function copyToClipboard() {
    var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textArea.value = "test copying";
    btnPos.appendChild(textArea);
    textArea.select();

    try {
        var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
        var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
        console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
    }

    document.body.removeChild(textArea);
}
```

In this code I have to append the text area to the webpage(after button click) before copying it. But I don't want the textarea to be shown I want to just copy the data inside the textarea without displaying the textarea.

Comment: Why dont you just add `textArea.value =''` after  `document.execCommand('copy');`

Comment: what is understand you will be removing the text area which will be pretty fast , any way you can hide the text area by 
`textArea.style.display="none"`

Comment: If display is set to none then .select won't work and hence nothing will get copied.
I found the solution, I will post it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
textArea.style.height = "0px";
textArea.style.width = "0px";
textArea.style.opacity = "0";
```

Adding this code hides the text area.

But even better solution was already in my code, I just made a little mistake in it.
I wrote

```js
document.body.removeChild(textArea);
```

While actually I had to write

```js
btnPos.removeChild(textArea);
```

this removes the text area after copying and its so fast that you can't even see the text area appear and disappear.